# Load data and images from json file by clicking on button and then button disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Doen anyone know how by clicking on “Load more” button additional items should load below the existing ones and “Load more” button should disappear. Additional  items should be loaded from the provided JSON file (numbers.json).

```js
[
    {
        "itemClass":"apps col-xs-6",
        "image_src": "images/1.png",
        "title": "One"
    },
    {
        "itemClass": "web col-xs-6",
        "image_src": "images/2.png",
        "title": "Two"
    },
    {
        "itemClass": "icons col-xs-6",
        "image_src": "images/3.png",
        "title": "Three"    
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please include code here, like what you have, how you are loading data via Ajax Requests, etc. To have the best chance of getting an accurate answer, try to include a JsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load-more').click(function() {

        $.getJSON( "numbers.json", function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            var items = [];
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
            });

            $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
            }).appendTo( "body" );

        });

        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

In the above code the load more button(with id="load-more") get the data from the json file and adds it to the html then removes the button itself after loading the json.

Comment: when i click button,button disappear but nothing show on the page.In console i've got this message : jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Joel/Desktop/FE/numbers.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: When running it in locally, you need to use a server to make http request for the json file

Comment: i used wamp as a server,but it doesn't work ,button disappear but nothing else happen

Comment: Is the json file in the same folder as your website?

Comment: If the file is in the same folder as the website then the cross origin problem should only appear if you are opening the file by double clicking it. If u are using wamp and running the website using localhost, this problem probably should not be there.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: Now it's working,thanks. When i open console i got this message :Array[3]0: Object1: Object2: Object length: 3__proto__: Array[0]

Do u know how to show all of this content from this number,json file on page(i guess some divs in html),but don't know what to do in js?Do you know maybe? Thanks a lot for help

Comment: the javascript above creates a ul list with the items in the file

Comment: If it works for you can you accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok ok,can u tell me how to show on page all the items from the ul list ? No,problem i'll accept ,u help me a lot,thanks